# How to highlight a TextView or LinearLayout when click it?

Tags: android

I have a LinearLayout that contains three TextViews. I want to highlight a TextView or the whole Layout when user clicks on the TextView. Is they any way to make it happen?

Thanks.

Answer (score 17):

I suppose 2 Layouts

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"

    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/root"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:clickable="true"
        >
...
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

findViewById(R.id.root).setOnClickListener(...);
```

Comment: Your hint with the selectableItemBackground worked for me like a charm. Should be the accepted answer!

Answer (score 7):

I couldn't get Roman's methods working, but found my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263169/android-how-to-make-view-highlight-when-clicked) instead.  Use an XML resource as the background drawable and voila! it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of ways of doing this.

The simplest way of doing this is by playing around with various [View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) attributes such as `android:focusable`, `android:focusableInTouchMode`, `android:clickable`, and [TextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) attributes such as `android:selectAllOnFocus`.

You could also customize the appearance of your views by setting their backgrounds to [StateListDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html)s (a.k.a. `<selector>` drawables).