# Android how to make View highlight when clicked?

Tags: android, xml, listview, layout, user-interface

I have a linear layout in which each row is inflated programatically and I want the rows to behave like the ListView when clicked on. That is, I want the row to highlight in the exact same way/colour that the default ListView does. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Ok I have finally figured out how to do this...basically it is done using a selector like the color selector linked by style except instead of 'color' use a drawable for the states and you can refer to the default list drawable that is used in ListView by this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@android:drawable/list_selector_background" />      
</selector>
```

and using this xml as the background for my View.

All the public default drawables can be found here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.drawable.html

Comment: If you're like me and need some background on how to use this kind of selector, read: http://android-journey.blogspot.com/2009/12/android-selectors.html

Comment: Do you happen to know how to keep the textview selected? I have two fragments 1 a listview and 1 a textview of info. Once an item in the listview is selected the item in the textview changes. Is there a way to keep the selected listitem selected?

Answer (score 23):

I was able to do the same with a text view that I wanted to behave like a list item by using:

```
<Textview
....
android:background="@android:drawable/list_selector_background"
/>
```

Comment: Good answer. For API 11 and above, use instead `android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"`. More info [here:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5546514/making-a-linearlayout-act-like-an-button)

Comment: ..and with appcompat-v7 library you can now use ?attr/selectableItemBackground for backwards compatibility

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/ColorStateList.html) might be a good place to start looking.

Although, i would advise you to use the ListView itself, rather than implementing it again.

Comment: I would use the ListView however I need it NOT to scroll and place it inside a ScrolView and that doesn't seem possible(??)...So I ended up trying to implement my own ListView of sort using a LinearLayout.

Comment: and thanks or the link...but would it be possible to reference and use the default ListViews selector element rather than create my own?

Comment: you could possibly search for the XML inside the Android Source Code...and just copy it over? i'm not sure if you refer the existing selector,otherwise.

Comment: Sorry couldnt figur out which one the ListView uses...anyways I tried creating my own but it doesnt seem to be working but am having problems:

I want the whole LinearLayout to highlight so what attribute do I set as the colour selector? I tried using textColour but that doesn't seem to work and background makes it crash since I can only set a drawable or single colour as a background :S

Answer (score 2):

if you still have a problem with that then please remember that some of UI elements are not clickable (RelativeLayout), so you have to add one more line:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    ....
    android:clickable="true"
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

To your listview set property

```
android:listSelector="@color/test"
```

and this test color set any transparent color you like. you can create any transparent color by using [hex transparent color](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17239853/3392323)