# Image and text grouped in a button

Tags: android, xml, button

I'd like to know, how to insert image and text into button, and center it with, for example 20dp margin between them. Please take a look at this screenshot:

[image: That's how it looks now]

As you can see, the image is aligned to the left, and the text has moved to the right (now it's not centered like texts from other buttons).
Here's a code for that:

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button_trombocyty"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button_erytrocyty"
    android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_normal"
    android:text="@string/button_trombocyty"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="14sp" 
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/krew"
    android:drawablePadding="10dp" />
```

I'd like to do something like this:
[image]

Could you tell me please, what should I change? Thank you!

Comment: just add image and text view in linear layout.And add gradient on linearlayout , I think ,it exactly look like button

Comment: try adding `android:gravity` or `android:layout_gravity` with `center` value to `Button`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep using Button and use HTML `<img>` tag.

**First create new string**

```
<string name="button_with_img">&lt;img src=\'%1$d\'>%2$s</string>
```

**Then in your code**

```
final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
//load formatted string from resources
//it requires 2 parameters in exact order: drawable id, button's text
String text = getString(R.string.button_with_img, R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Button text");
Spanned spannedText = Html.fromHtml(text, new Html.ImageGetter() {
    @Override
    public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
        int id = Integer.parseInt(source);
        Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(id);
        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
        return drawable;
    }
}, null);

button.setText(spannedText);
```

It may be needed to adjust setting bounds for drawable.

Answer (score 0):

I think You should add something like this

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/hover" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/krew" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Apply gradian in background

hover.xml

```
< ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:shape="rectangle">
 <gradient
  android:startColor="#f1f1f2"// color you want
  android:centerColor="#e7e7e8"
  android:endColor="#cfcfcf"
  android:angle="270" />
 </shape>
```

Comment: Thank you, but even if it looks like a button, it doesn't have possibilities of doing some actions, for example on long press etc. :(

Comment: @Macieg, You can use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLongClickListener.html  onlong click listener on Linearlayout, and also you can apply click event on image and textview separately

Comment: Still you find some issue than check here,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5546514/making-a-linearlayout-act-like-an-button

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
<LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   style="@android:style/Widget.Button"
   android:gravity="center">
   <ImageView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
      android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

   <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Image caption"
      android:textColor="@android:color/black"
      android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you, but even if it looks like a button, it doesn't have possibilities of doing some actions, for example on long press etc. :(

Comment: have you try to handle Linearlayout Long click listener  ?