# Android: How to align the CheckBox text in the bottom?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-checkbox

Basically what I want is to have is a checkbox with the icon and the text below to the icon, something like this:

```
 -------------------
|   CheckBox Icon   |
|                   |
|   CheckBox Text   |
|                   |
 -------------------
```

By default the icon is placed in the left and the text in the right, both of them at the same level. Below the layout I'm using:

```
<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Switch state"
    android:button="@drawable/my_custom_selector" />
```

Any idea about how can I achieve to have the icon on top and the text below the icon?. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you please post your XML from your layout?

Comment: I had the same problem and I have solved it using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65395986/13321079)

Answer (score 21):

I had the same problem and I have solved it using this:

```
android:button="@null"
android:drawableTop="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
```

Answer (score 7):

CheckedTextView + state list with checked and unchecked drawables:

```
<CheckedTextView
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/checkmark"
    android:checked="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Checked text"/>
```

@drawable/checkmark

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/unchecked" android:state_checked="false"></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/checked"></item></selector>
```

(checkmark.xml is simplified).

Answer (score 1):

You can make the `LinearLayout` vertical and put the `CheckBox` (without text) on top and the text in a `TextView` below.

Finally make the `LinearLayout` [clickable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5546514/making-a-linearlayout-act-like-an-button) and check/uncheck programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

I just made it by using a linear layout (vertical) as i don't use any custom checkbox xml

my case is like a text is on top of a checkbox

```
 <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                >
                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    android:layout_width="15dp"
                    android:layout_height="15dp"
                    android:text="text1"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="15dp"/>
                <CheckBox android:id="@+id/textcheckbox"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"/>
            </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

Answer (score 0):

The above solution did not work for me. What was missing is the Kotlin/Java code in it.

So add it in your Kotlin code

```
cb_twitter.setOnClickListener({
            (it as CheckedTextView).toggle()
        })
```

Here is my XML Code:

```
<CheckedTextView
    android:id="@+id/cb_twitter"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:checked="false"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/checkbox_selector_twitter"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="@string/Twitter"
    android:textAlignment="gravity"/>
```

Here I have also made text to center by

```
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:textAlignment="gravity"
```