# How can I align checkbox with text to right side of the screen?

Tags: android, checkbox

I have a checkbox inside a `TableRow`. I would like to align both checkbox and text to the right side of the screen but when I use `android:gravity="right"` it only aligns the text to the right side of the screen but not the square (the checkbox itself). It seems that they are aligned separately (checkbox on the left and text on the right side of the screen).

Here is the snippet of xml that refers to the checkbox:

```
<TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

          <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Select"
                android:id="@+id/checkboxSelect"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="right"/>
</TableRow>
```

How can I align both the checkbox and the text on it to the right side of the screen?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you mean checkbox text move to the right but box not moving??

Comment: @Andolasoft Yes, exactly that. The text is moving to the right side of the screen but the box is still on the left side of the screen.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3156781/how-to-show-android-checkbox-at-right-side..  may this help you..

Comment: Which parent layout table layout contains ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attribute `android:gravity` is working on view itself, while `android:layout_gravity` is suggestion for parent view to align it's child.

if you want tell parent layout to align it's child at left or right you have two options:

1. use  `android:gravity` on parent, and thus parent will try to align all child views at that gravity.
2. `android:layout_gravity` on child view, and only this view will try to align itself in that gravity.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your explanation is the only who works for me. An addition to your answer, I had to remove `android:layout_weight="1"`.

Answer (score 8):

Simply add `Checkbox` as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CheckBox xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:text="hello"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:button="@null"
    android:drawableRight="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"/>
```

> It will show you `text` at left and `check box` at right.

Comment: It'd be helpful if you could also explain what does this code do? `android:button="@null"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You will get both text and checkbox to the right side

```
<TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:gravity="right">

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkboxSelect"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
            android:text="Select" />
    </TableRow>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `RelativeLayout`

```
<RelativeLayout 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

      <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/text_view"
            android:id="@+id/checkboxSelect"/>

      <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/text_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    <CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center|end"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:button="@null"
    android:drawableRight="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
    android:text="hello" />
```

Set android:button="@null"
and
set this drawable "?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
as drawableRight or drawableLeft as you like.