# Android - Is it possible to put a Switch inside Button?

Tags: android, android-layout, button, android-switch

Is it possible to insert a switch inside a button? Like for example in the standard alarm app on Samsung smartphones.

Comment: found a possible solution, just made a clickable LinearLayout [link to solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5546514/making-a-linearlayout-act-like-an-button)

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Samsung uses a clickable LinearLayout, and there is a button inside that layout. Buttons cant have children.

Comment: I want to have a function similar to the standard Samsung alarm app. Thanks, i already linked a detailied answer for how to implement a clickable LinearLayout.